# datepicker (ignore invalid dates)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Hey guy's I have a datepicker where I have disabled the weekends. But the problem is that the user can type the date that is in the weekend

```
$("[name=startdatecontract]").datepicker({  
    minDate : 2,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

The user must be able to write it. But I need something that ignores or gives error when the date is in the weekend. + if the date is not 2 days from today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

here i check user typed date is weekend or not and (+ if the date is not 2 days from today) on `change` function

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
minDate : 2,
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends 
}).on("change", function(e) {
var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
var minDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
var maxDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + minDate));
var datee=(this.value, curDate)>=maxDate?(this.value, curDate):null;
    if(datee!==null){
          var day = datee.getDay();
          if (day==6||day==0) {
              alert("invalid date");
              this.value="";
          }
     }
     else{
           alert("invalid date");
           this.value="";
     }
    });
```

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
minDate : 2,
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends 
}).on("change", function(e) {
var curDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
var minDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
var maxDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + minDate));
var datee=(this.value, curDate)>=maxDate?(this.value, curDate):null;
if(datee!==null){
      var day = datee.getDay();
      if (day==6||day==0) {
          alert("invalid date");
          this.value="";
      }
 }
 else{
       alert("invalid date");
       this.value="";
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="block">
  <input id="datepicker" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkDate(){

    var a = document.getElementById("startdatecontract").value;
    var dates = a.split("-");
    a = dates[1]+'/'+dates[0]+'/'+dates[2];
    var d = new Date();

    if((d.getMonth() + 1)<=9)
    {
        var today = '0'+(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    }
    else
    {
        var today=(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    }
    today=today.toString(); 
    a = new Date(a).getTime();
    today = new Date(today).getTime();

    if (a < today)
    {
        $("#startdatecontract").val("");
        alert("Availability date should not be past date.");
        document.getElementById("startdatecontract").value = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thnx for your time ;)